# What UNICODE characters should I use to write LaTeX?

Tags: unicode

Assume I write something about LaTeX in email. I use UTF-8 so I can use any UNICODE character I want. Which characters should I technically use for name "LaTeX"? I believe that LaTeX originally did not mean letters L + a + T + e + X (that is, mixture of uppercase and lowercase ASCII characters). I know that usually LaTeX is written in ASCII characters only outside LaTeX source code where one just enters `\LaTeX`.

Comment: The name is latex or LaTeX, there is no special unicode involved. `\LaTeX` is a logo. I normally use latex or pdflatex when I mean the application or when I'm lazy, and LaTeX for the format.

Comment: I think the question is mainly if the X should be `Greek Capital Letter Xi`

Comment: U+004c LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
  U+0054 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
  U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E
  U+0058 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X

Comment: Why not U+004C LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A U+03A4 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER TAU U+0395 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER EPSILON U+03A7 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER CHI as in LAΤΕΧ?

Comment: As far as I know, the defintion of the command `\TeX` which typesets the TeX logo (as part of the LaTeX logo) is just `{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}` and thus does not use Greek characters. Therefore, I see no point in using Greek characters for writing an Unicode version of the logo either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `latex` logo does not contain any special characters. It has only normal uppercase roman letters. It is traditionally typed in `latex` itself with said logo with the command `\LaTeX`. Outside of `latex`, people usually write "LaTeX" or "latex". Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Pronouncing_and_writing_.22LaTeX.22) on this.

Comment: The Wikipedia article could use some editing, but any time I've tried to correct anything in Wikipedia regarding TeX, It's been rejected.  Too bad.  I was there.  Regarding the logo, it is best rendered as "LaTeX", no fancy coding unless you know exactly what you're doing.  Even publishers of LaTeX-related books have been known to get it wrong on book covers.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Did you add links to references for your changes that got reverted? Wikipedia seems to be really strict about rule "No original research" nowadays. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_original_research for more details.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen -- No, I almost certainly didn't add links, because what I was trying to correct was code and reasoning for the change to conform to "best practices".  Even usually good sources sometimes slip up on such things, by either omission or commission, so finding a suitable link may not be easy, if even possible.  I can only go on my own experience which apparently isn't recognized unless it's been published in something I've actually written.  Makes no sense, and isn't worth the effort, so I just don't recommend the LaTeX Wikibook.

Comment: I agree that it would be much better for Wikipedia to allow original research, too, as long as it's clearly written as such. However, I understand their reasoning if they want to be a *pure* dictionary replacement only.

Answer (score 4):

At least currently, there isn't a way to replicate the appearance of the LaTeX logo in normal text with Unicode. If you're using LaTeX, just use `\LaTeX` to insert the logo. If you're using some other typesetting program, you *may* be able to shift the letters around to match the logo. But otherwise, it's probably best just to stick to the standard plaintext "LaTeX". If you try hard enough you can come up with some fancier options, but none of them are particularly attractive (LᴬTᴇX? LᵃTₑX?), and definitely none of them is official.